# How to get the type of credit card from a Magento\Sales\Model\Order?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

My ultimate goal is to include the type of credit card (Visa, Mastercard etc.) into order emails. Assume that customer always chooses to pay with a card.

I tried adding `{{var order.getPayment().getCcType()}}` in `order_new.html` email template, but it prints nothing. `order` variable is set correctly, I can get some other properties of `order.getPayment()` to display in the email.

In order to debug this, here is what I do in an observer that fires at `email_order_set_template_vars_before` event:

```
/** @var Payment $payment */
$payment = $observer->getData('transport')['order']->getPayment();
var_dump($payment->getCcType());
die;
```

Then I go to Admin panel, choose an order I placed that is to be paid with a credit card, and press "Send email" at the order page, to resend the email a test customer should have received. The observer (code above) prints `NULL`.

I don't know what else I can try. Why is `$payment->getCcType()` `NULL` when I chose a credit card?